# Neo4j custom Cypher @Query containing RegEx returns no result

Tags: spring, neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I have the following custom query in my `Neo4jRepository` (I'm using Spring Boot with Spring Data Neo4j):

```
@Query("MATCH (n:Component) WHERE n.path =~ '/path/{0}/.*/{1}' RETURN n")
Component findByTenantAndName(String tenant, String name);
```

When I run this query within the application it returns `null` with the following log statement:

```
2018-01-12 10:58:27.744  INFO 74294 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.n.o.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest   : Request: MATCH (n:Component) WHERE n.path =~ '/path/{0}/.*/{1}' RETURN n with params {0=foo, 1=baz}
2018-01-12 10:58:27.763  WARN 74294 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] d.c.a.service.MyService  : Could not find parent component named 'baz' for tenant 'foo'
```

But, if I go to the Cypher backend at http://localhost:7474 and run the query:

```
MATCH (n:Component) WHERE n.path =~ '/path/foo/.*/baz' RETURN n
```

I get exactly one `Component` result with path `/path/foo/bar/baz`. What's wrong with my custom query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@Query("MATCH (n:Component) WHERE n.path =~ {0} RETURN n")
Component findByTenantAndName(String query);
```

And from the service where you call this. pass the whole regex like this

```
String query = "/path/<tenant>/.*/<name>"; // replace tenant and name with actual variables.
findByTenantAndName(query)
```

Comment: Or use `MATCH (n:Component) WHERE n.path =~ '/path/'+{0}+'/.*/'+{1} RETURN n`

Comment: Thank you both. Passing the whole string definitely works. I will also try out to separate the parameters from the string as proposed by Michael.